# React clickable drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing some react code and in one of the components, I am trying to add a dropdown from https://atlassian.design/components/dropdown-menu/examples

My dropdown component is

```
import React from 'react';

import DropdownMenu, { DropdownItem, DropdownItemGroup } from '@atlaskit/dropdown-menu';

const DropdownMenuDefaultExample = () => (
<DropdownMenu trigger="Page actions" triggerType="button">
    <DropdownItemGroup>
    <DropdownItem>Edit</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Share</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Move</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Clone</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Delete</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem>Report</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownItemGroup>
</DropdownMenu>
);

export default DropdownMenuDefaultExample;
```

When I call this component from another component, it loads fine and I can see the drop down options as well.
Now I want to use these dropdown options as filters. So when use clicks Edit do something, when they click share do something else.

I tried adding OnClick events but the dropdown menu or the items aren't clickable.

I made a small one line change to see if I am able to capture the clicks such as

```
<DropdownItem onClick={console.log('clicked Edit')}>Edit</DropdownItem>
```

but this isn't working.

Has anyone been able to get dropdowns to work?

Comment: Try passing a function rather than calling console log? `onClick={() => console.log(...)}`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox

I tried this 

    function sayHello() {
       alert('Hello!');
    }

and also changed

    <DropdownItem onClick={sayHello}>Edit</DropdownItem>


but that didn't work